# AngularJS, PhantomJS, and ng-repeat problems

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using PhantomJS to generate snapshots of my Angular application, as explained [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html).

To do this, I have a PhantomJS script that reads a URL, spitting the HTML to console, plus a Node script that reads my sitemap.xml and runs the PhantomJS script for each URL.

Within my application, I also have a flag that gets tripped when the application thinks everything has rendered. I was pretty conservative about the way this flag gets set, just to be sure that everything really does get rendered before PhantomJS grabs the HTML.

The problem I'm having is this. The application's menu is created using an ng-repeat and an unordered list. For this directive -- and this directive only -- what happens is that the list elements get repeated at least twice (more than that, actually.)

Suppose the menu looked like this, with three items:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item.text}}</li>
```

My snapshot script, using PhantomJS, produces HTML like this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item.text}}</li>        
   <li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item.text}}</li>
   <li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item.text}}</li>
```

If I load this in the browser, Angular dutifully executes the ng-repeat directives *again*, leaving me with nine menu items (3 of each.)

This is obviously not what I want, but I'm not sure why it is happening, either. And I don't know if the problem is with something in Angular or something in PhantomJS. Also, to make matters more frustrating, there are other ng-repeat directives on the page that execute just fine.

One other thing. The menu block is within an ng-if. I'm not sure if that matters, but maybe it does.

So what's going on? Anyone experience this issue before?

EDIT:

Here's the code that sets the flag. Since I'm using the ui router, I wait for $viewContentLoaded events. This event gets triggered whenever a view is loaded. When the event is triggered, I set or reset a timeout that will change the flag on $rootScope. Because I have nested views, the event gets triggered multiple times per page load. The idea is to wait 15 seconds from the last time this event occurs, then set the flag.

```
var timeout = null;
$scope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function(){
    var interval = 15000; //15 seconds
   $rootScope.domStatus = 'notReady'; 
    function setDomStatus(){
        $rootScope.domStatus = 'ready';
    }

    if(timeout){
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    }  
    timeout = $timeout(setDomStatus, interval);

});
```

One last thought:

Now I'm beginning to wonder if this really matters. The snapshots are meant to be loaded by search engines, which won't execute the JavaScript (indeed, that's why snapshots are made in the first place.) For good measure, I could tell Express to look for search engines and NOT load scripts in such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering about the same issue. But the behaviour is correct. Here's why:

PhantomJS renders your AngularJS webpage.

The 'problem' you are facing is that in the output html you still have your javascript code and angular directives. If you're viewing the output in your browser the whole AngularJS / javascript code gets executed again.

So having this simple angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('webApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
            $scope.values = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'];
        });
```

along with this html body:

```
<body ng-app="webApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="val in values">
            {{val}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The ouput html rendered by PhantomJS looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="webApp" class="ng-scope">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="ng-scope">
            <!-- ngRepeat: val in values --><div ng-repeat="val in values" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            AAA
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: val in values --><div ng-repeat="val in values" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            BBB
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: val in values --><div ng-repeat="val in values" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            CCC
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: val in values -->
        </div>

</body>
```

Now this output is **supposed for javascript disabled** browsers and search engine robots. Since they don't execute the javascript anymore they get the desired output

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

If you view this html in your javascript enabled browser all the 'ng-repeat' directives get executed again which creates the outcome

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
CCC
CCC
CCC
```

To view the PhantomJS rendered html the way it is supposed to look you would have to turn off javascript functionality in your browser. (E.g. in Firefox: enter 'about:config' in your url bar and change 'javascript.enabled' to false)

Comment: Thank you! Very succinct. I believe I understand now!

Comment: yes you nailed it right, disable the Js in the browser and everything is fine again !

Answer (score 0):

It look like PhantomJS is catching the page while angular is busy running this particular ng-repeat (the ng-if might indeed be the cause for that). If you add a delay before capturing the page, it should work better. If it does you either keep the delay, or you fix the flag you mentioned.

With some more details on how you're setting the flag we might find a solution for that.